# Why Linux Mint 20 takes lot of time to boot on latest generation hardware?

Tags: linux-mint, boot

Why **Linux mint 20** is taking around **1 minute 30 seconds to 2 minutes** to boot on i310G I really am frustrated with sluggish boot time. I am trying for find a solution from last 1 week but no fruitful results yet.

I would be humbly thankful to the community for the answer.

**systemd-analyze**

```
 Startup finished in 10.699s (firmware) + 3.368s (loader) + 7.923s (kernel) + 30.193s (userspace) = 52.185s 
        graphical.target reached after 30.181s in userspace
```

**$ systemd-analyze blame**

```
9.913s accounts-daemon.service                                                                  
9.303s dev-sda7.device                                                                          
8.674s ubuntu-system-adjustments.service                                                        
8.229s NetworkManager.service                                                                   
6.241s avahi-daemon.service                                                                     
6.239s bluetooth.service                                                                        
6.081s thermald.service                                                                         
6.073s wpa_supplicant.service                                                                   
6.072s systemd-logind.service                                                                   
5.087s systemd-journal-flush.service
```

**systemd-analyze critical-chain**

```
  graphical.target @30.181s
  └─multi-user.target @27.593s
    └─getty.target @27.593s
      └─getty@tty1.service @27.592s
        └─system-getty.slice @27.590s
          └─setvtrgb.service @27.461s +126ms
            └─systemd-user-sessions.service @25.740s +34ms
              └─network.target @25.735s
                └─NetworkManager.service @17.505s +8.229s
                  └─dbus.service @17.503s
                    └─basic.target @17.430s
                      └─sockets.target @17.430s
                        └─uuidd.socket @17.430s
                          └─sysinit.target @17.374s
                            └─systemd-timesyncd.service @17.012s +361ms
                              └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @15.529s +1.271s
                                └─local-fs.target @15.402s
                                  └─boot-efi.mount @15.300s +101ms
                                    └─systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-BC85\x2dD177.service @13.996s +1.279s
                                      └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-BC85\x2dD177.device @13.995s
```

**inxi -Fxi**

**cat /etc/fstab**

```
    # / was on /dev/sda7 during installation
    UUID=ca57e331-79fb-4f04-b68e-7f2de5247b1a /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
    # /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
    UUID=BC85-D177  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
    # /home was on /dev/sda9 during installation
    UUID=47c8dbf8-dec0-4238-8c0e-8582def09194 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
    # swap was on /dev/sda8 during installation
    UUID=00d38b07-5422-46f2-8ed7-82fc3186f50b none            swap    sw              0       0
```

**blkid**

```
    zahid@Zahid-HP15s ~ $ blkid
        /dev/sda1: LABEL="SYSTEM" UUID="BC85-D177" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="7c859521-1909-42cc-9d5d-6fbbf2b72a77"
        /dev/sda3: LABEL="Windows" UUID="1A0066FD0066DF6F" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="8dfca0e5-c889-441a-ad8a-415c0f445e31"
        /dev/sda4: LABEL="New Volume" UUID="F0C88F71C88F34BE" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="648dffd2-e679-4125-a5ed-490568be4fc6"
        /dev/sda5: LABEL="New Volume" UUID="ACF205FCF205CC10" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="cb143e3e-20c2-4128-8394-d34405816d66"
        /dev/sda6: LABEL="Windows RE tools" UUID="BE1AC1A01AC155D5" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="bfa3e33d-0db2-4b5c-a804-8c5ef4f356f7"
        /dev/sda7: UUID="ca57e331-79fb-4f04-b68e-7f2de5247b1a" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="a2c0f78a-d763-44b8-9a33-a535095218ed"
        /dev/sda8: UUID="00d38b07-5422-46f2-8ed7-82fc3186f50b" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="80c26d41-bcd4-4f77-a705-10ae5d7266c6"
        /dev/sda9: UUID="47c8dbf8-dec0-4238-8c0e-8582def09194" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="9d2f1025-b6a4-465e-b0ad-c4a4b4336c24"
```

**sudo cat /var/log/boot.log**

```
            ------------ Thu Sep 03 16:27:11 IST 2020 ------------
            /dev/sda7: clean, 509970/6250496 files, 4357931/24999936 blocks
            [  OK  ] Finished Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data.
            [  OK  ] Finished Clean up any mess left by 0dns-up.
            [  OK  ] Finished Create Volatile Files and Directories.
                     Starting Network Name Resolution...
                     Starting Network Time Synchronization...
                     Starting Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown...
            [  OK  ] Finished Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown.
            [  OK  ] Finished Load AppArmor profiles.
                     Starting Raise network interfaces...
            [  OK  ] Started Network Time Synchronization.
            [  OK  ] Reached target System Initialization.
            [  OK  ] Started ACPI Events Check.
            [  OK  ] Started CUPS Scheduler.
            [  OK  ] Started Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
            [  OK  ] Reached target Paths.
            [  OK  ] Reached target System Time Set.
            [  OK  ] Reached target System Time Synchronized.
            [  OK  ] Started Trigger anacron every hour.
            [  OK  ] Started Daily apt download activities.
            [  OK  ] Started Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
            [  OK  ] Started Periodic ext4 Online Metadata Check for All Filesystems.
            [  OK  ] Started Discard unused blocks once a week.
            [  OK  ] Started Refresh fwupd metadata regularly.
            [  OK  ] Started Daily rotation of log files.
            [  OK  ] Started Daily man-db regeneration.
            [  OK  ] Started Message of the Day.
            [  OK  ] Reached target Timers.
            [  OK  ] Listening on ACPID Listen Socket.
            [  OK  ] Listening on Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack Activation Socket.
            [  OK  ] Listening on CUPS Scheduler.
            [  OK  ] Listening on D-Bus System Message Bus Socket.
            [  OK  ] Listening on UUID daemon activation socket.
            [  OK  ] Reached target Sockets.
            [  OK  ] Reached target Basic System.
                     Starting Accounts Service...
            [  OK  ] Started ACPI event daemon.
                     Starting Save/Restore Sound Card State...
                     Starting Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack...
                     Starting Bluetooth service...
            [  OK  ] Started Regular background program processing daemon.
            [  OK  ] Started CUPS Scheduler.
            [  OK  ] Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
                     Starting Network Manager...
            [  OK  ] Started Save initial kernel messages after boot.
                     Starting Remove Stale Online ext4 Metadata Check Snapshots...
                     Starting Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes...
                     Starting LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB...
                     Starting GRUB failed boot detection...
                     Starting LSB: disk temperature monitoring daemon...
            [  OK  ] Started irqbalance daemon.
                     Starting Initialize hardware monitoring sensors...
                     Starting LSB: Load kernel modules needed to enable cpufreq scaling...
            [  OK  ] Started mintsystem.service.
            [  OK  ] Started Set the CPU Frequency Scaling governor.
                     Starting Restore /etc/resolv.conf if the system crashed before the ppp link was shut down...
                     Starting LSB: Adaptive readahead daemon...
                     Starting System Logging Service...
                     Starting Login Service...
                     Starting Thermal Daemon Service...
                     Starting Ubuntu system adjustments...
                     Starting Disk Manager...
                     Starting WPA supplicant...
            [  OK  ] Finished Raise network interfaces.
            [  OK  ] Finished Restore /etc/resolv.conf if the system crashed before the ppp link was shut down.
            [  OK  ] Finished Save/Restore Sound Card State.
            [  OK  ] Finished Initialize hardware monitoring sensors.
            [  OK  ] Started LSB: disk temperature monitoring daemon.
            [  OK  ] Reached target Sound Card.
            [  OK  ] Finished Remove Stale Online ext4 Metadata Check Snapshots.
            [  OK  ] Started LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB.
            [  OK  ] Started LSB: Load kernel modules needed to enable cpufreq scaling.
                     Starting LSB: set CPUFreq kernel parameters...
            [  OK  ] Finished GRUB failed boot detection.
            [  OK  ] Started System Logging Service.
            [  OK  ] Started LSB: set CPUFreq kernel parameters.
            [  OK  ] Started Network Name Resolution.
            [  OK  ] Reached target Host and Network Name Lookups.
                     Starting Tool to automatically collect and submit kernel crash signatures...
            [  OK  ] Started LSB: Adaptive readahead daemon.
            [  OK  ] Started Tool to automatically collect and submit kernel crash signatures.
            [  OK  ] Finished Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes.
```

Analysing the *journalctl* there's a minute of delay at the end of his **journalctl** after a reboot as follows:

```
            Aug 29 13:24:06 Zahid-HP15s udisksd[1008]: Failed to load the 'mdraid' libblockdev plugin
                Aug 29 13:24:10 Zahid-HP15s wpa_supplicant[1009]: dbus: fill_dict_with_properties dbus_interface=fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.Interface.P2PDevice dbus_property=P2PDeviceConfig getter failed
                Aug 29 13:24:10 Zahid-HP15s NetworkManager[988]: <warn>  [1598687650.7084] device (wlo1): wifi-scan: active scanning for networks due to profiles with wifi.hidden=yes. This makes you trackable
                Aug 29 13:24:13 Zahid-HP15s wpa_supplicant[1009]: bgscan simple: Failed to enable signal strength monitoring
                Aug 29 13:24:23 Zahid-HP15s systemd-resolved[913]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
                Aug 29 13:24:23 Zahid-HP15s systemd-resolved[913]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
                Aug 29 13:24:30 Zahid-HP15s /slick-greeter-set-keyboard-layout[2973]: Result: Warning! Multiple definitions of keyboard model
                                                                                      Warning! Multiple definitions of keyboard layout
                Aug 29 13:25:16 Zahid-HP15s cinnamon-session[6142]: WARNING: t+0.30993s: Could not read /home/zahid/.config/autostart/warpinator-autostart.desktop: Key file does not have key “Name” in group “Desktop Entry”
                Aug 29 13:25:27 Zahid-HP15s cinnamon-session[6142]: WARNING: t+10.73768s: Detected that screensaver has appeared on the bus
```

**zahid@Zahid-HP15s ~ $ cat  /var/log/syslog | grep error***

```
Sep  3 16:27:16 Zahid-HP15s kernel: [    0.317325] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.RP05.PCRP._ON due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20200528/psparse-529)
            Sep  3 16:27:16 Zahid-HP15s kernel: [    2.225653] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: DPC: error containment capabilities: Int Msg #0, RPExt+ PoisonedTLP+ SwTrigger+ RP PIO Log 4, DL_ActiveErr+
            Sep  3 16:27:16 Zahid-HP15s kernel: [    2.226157] pcieport 0000:00:1d.1: DPC: error containment capabilities: Int Msg #0, RPExt+ PoisonedTLP+ SwTrigger+ RP PIO Log 4, DL_ActiveErr+
            Sep  3 16:27:16 Zahid-HP15s kernel: [   12.536398] EXT4-fs (sda7): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
            Sep  3 16:27:21 Zahid-HP15s thermald[722]: [WARN]error: could not parse file /etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml
            Sep  3 16:27:21 Zahid-HP15s thermald[722]: [WARN]error: could not parse file /etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml
            Sep  3 16:27:21 Zahid-HP15s thermald[722]: [WARN]error: could not parse file /etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml
```

**cat /var/log/dmesg**:

```
                            [    8.361162] systemd[1]: Inserted module 'autofs4'
                            [    8.973333] systemd[1]: systemd 245.4-4ubuntu3.2 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN2 -IDN +PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid)
                            [    8.992651] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86-64.
                            [    9.030608] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <Zahid-HP15s>.
                            [   11.633242] systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/dbus.socket:5: ListenStream= references a path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket → /run/dbus/system_bus_socket; please update the unit file accordingly.
                            [   12.148373] systemd[1]: Created slice system-modprobe.slice.
                            [   12.148593] systemd[1]: Created slice system-systemd\x2dfsck.slice.
                            [   12.148858] systemd[1]: Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
                            [   12.148882] systemd[1]: Reached target User and Group Name Lookups.
                            [   12.148891] systemd[1]: Reached target Remote File Systems.
                            [   12.148895] systemd[1]: Reached target Slices.
                            [   12.148942] systemd[1]: Listening on Device-mapper event daemon FIFOs.
                            [   12.148992] systemd[1]: Listening on LVM2 poll daemon socket.
                            [   12.166706] systemd[1]: Listening on Syslog Socket.
                            [   12.167731] systemd[1]: Listening on Process Core Dump Socket.
                            [   12.167769] systemd[1]: Listening on fsck to fsckd communication Socket.
                            [   12.167792] systemd[1]: Listening on initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
                            [   12.167873] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Audit Socket.
                            [   12.167909] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket (/dev/log).
                            [   12.167949] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket.
                            [   12.167990] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Control Socket.
                            [   12.168021] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
                            [   12.168622] systemd[1]: Mounting Huge Pages File System...
                            [   12.169214] systemd[1]: Mounting POSIX Message Queue File System...
                            [   12.169972] systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Debug File System...
                            [   12.170549] systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Trace File System...
                            [   12.171551] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Service...
                            [   12.172413] systemd[1]: Starting Availability of block devices...
                            [   12.173585] systemd[1]: Starting Set the console keyboard layout...
                            [   12.174504] systemd[1]: Starting Create list of static device nodes for the current kernel...
                            [   12.175571] systemd[1]: Starting Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeventd or progress polling...
                            [   12.175611] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Load Kernel Module drm being skipped.
                            [   12.383942] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Set Up Additional Binary Formats being skipped.
                            [   12.383983] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in File System Check on Root Device being skipped.
                            [   12.420942] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Modules...
                            [   12.421690] systemd[1]: Starting Remount Root and Kernel File Systems...
                            [   12.422490] systemd[1]: Starting udev Coldplug all Devices...
                            [   12.423252] systemd[1]: Starting Uncomplicated firewall...
                            [   12.424317] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
                            [   12.536398] kernel: EXT4-fs (sda7): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
                            [   13.268397] kernel: bpfilter: Loaded bpfilter_umh pid 362
                            [   13.268469] unknown: Started bpfilter
                            [   13.853807] kernel: lp: driver loaded but no devices found
                            [   14.018916] kernel: ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
                            [   18.239605] kernel: input: HP Wireless hotkeys as /devices/virtual/input/input8
                            [   18.457909] kernel: mei_me 0000:00:16.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
                            [   18.662880] kernel: pstore: Using crash dump compression: deflate
                            [   18.662899] kernel: pstore: Registered efi as persistent store backend
                            [   18.674479] kernel: intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain package
                            [   18.674530] kernel: proc_thermal 0000:00:04.0: Creating sysfs group for PROC_THERMAL_PCI
                            [   18.728619] kernel: dw-apb-uart.2: ttyS4 at MMIO 0x4010002000 (irq = 20, base_baud = 7500000) is a 16550A
                            [   18.753628] kernel: ee1004 0-0050: 512 byte EE1004-compliant SPD EEPROM, read-only
                            [   18.834225] kernel: input: ELAN0709:00 04F3:30A0 Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/i2c_designware.0/i2c-1/i2c-ELAN0709:00/0018:04F3:30A0.0001/input/input10
                            [   18.834303] kernel: input: ELAN0709:00 04F3:30A0 Touchpad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/i2c_designware.0/i2c-1/i2c-ELAN0709:00/0018:04F3:30A0.0001/input/input12
                            [   18.834376] kernel: hid-multitouch 0018:04F3:30A0.0001: input,hidraw0: I2C HID v1.00 Mouse [ELAN0709:00 04F3:30A0] on i2c-ELAN0709:00
                            [   18.869646] kernel: cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database
                            [   18.869913] kernel: cfg80211: Loaded X.509 cert 'sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7'
                            [   18.874136] kernel: intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain package
                            [   18.874137] kernel: intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain core
                            [   18.874138] kernel: intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain uncore
                            [   19.014397] kernel: mei_hdcp 0000:00:16.0-b638ab7e-94e2-4ea2-a552-d1c54b627f04: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_hdcp_component_ops [i915])
                            [   19.233473] kernel: Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
                            [   19.233491] kernel: NET: Registered protocol family 31
                            [   19.233491] kernel: Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
                            [   19.233495] kernel: Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
                            [   19.233496] kernel: Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
                            [   19.233498] kernel: Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
                            [   19.487156] kernel: input: HP WMI hotkeys as /devices/virtual/input/input9
                            [   19.586363] kernel: mc: Linux media interface: v0.10
                            [   19.641041] kernel: rtl8821ce: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
                            [   19.641722] kernel: rtl8821ce: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
                            [   19.643816] kernel: rtl8821ce 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
                            [   19.743727] kernel: videodev: Linux video capture interface: v2.00
                            [   19.753481] kernel: rtl8821ce 0000:02:00.0 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
                            [   19.762035] kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
                            [   19.763134] kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=08 hci_rev=000c lmp_ver=08 lmp_subver=8821
                            [   19.764124] kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=1
                            [   19.764125] kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8821c_fw.bin
                            [   19.796235] kernel: RAPL PMU: API unit is 2^-32 Joules, 3 fixed counters, 655360 ms ovfl timer
                            [   19.796237] kernel: RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain pp0-core 2^-14 Joules
                            [   19.796237] kernel: RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain package 2^-14 Joules
                            [   19.796238] kernel: RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain pp1-gpu 2^-14 Joules
                            [   19.860696] kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8821c_config.bin
                            [   19.860774] kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: cfg_sz 10, total sz 21678
                            [   20.145893] kernel: uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device HP TrueVision HD Camera (0408:5365)
                            [   20.164444] kernel: uvcvideo 1-5:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 4 was not initialized!
                            [   20.164446] kernel: uvcvideo 1-5:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 3 was not initialized!
                            [   20.164446] kernel: uvcvideo 1-5:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 2 was not initialized!
                            [   20.164447] kernel: uvcvideo 1-5:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
                            [   20.164491] kernel: input: HP TrueVision HD Camera: HP Tru as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/input/input13
                            [   20.164534] kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
                            [   20.164535] kernel: USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
                            [   20.226540] kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040380
                            [   20.226562] kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
                            [   20.226774] kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
                            [   20.272168] kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: fw version 0x826ca99e
                            [   20.384793] kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC236: line_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
                            [   20.384795] kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
                            [   20.384796] kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x21/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
                            [   20.384797] kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
                            [   20.384797] kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
                            [   20.456176] kernel: input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input15
                            [   20.456204] kernel: input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input16
                            [   20.456231] kernel: input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input17
                            [   20.456258] kernel: input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input18
                            [   20.456280] kernel: input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input19
                            [   20.456302] kernel: input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input20
                            [   20.456327] kernel: input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=11 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input21
                            [   20.456348] kernel: input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=12 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input22
                            [   22.364592] kernel: Adding 3000316k swap on /dev/sda8.  Priority:-2 extents:1 across:3000316k FS
                            [   22.536315] kernel: EXT4-fs (sda9): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
                            [   24.658301] kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1599130632.907:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-senddoc" pid=668 comm="apparmor_parser"
                            [   24.920964] kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1599130633.171:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-xpdfimport" pid=678 comm="apparmor_parser"
                            [   24.973595] kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1599130633.223:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cups-browsed" pid=680 comm="apparmor_parser"
                            [   32.043775] kernel: Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
                            [   32.043778] kernel: Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
                            [   32.043783] kernel: Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
                            [   32.092795] kernel: NET: Registered protocol family 38
```

Comment: You can trim some of that time off by following [these directions](https://askmeaboutlinux.com/2019/11/28/how-to-speed-up-boot-time-on-linux-if-it-boots-slowly/).

Comment: @KGIII didn't work! Moreover, my boot time exceeds 2 minutes now after following your instructions.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions exactly? If so, there's no way the time can increase. Use cut/paste if need be.

Comment: @KGlll copy and pasted exactly. All the commands executed without error even. But no help or even worsened the situation. :(

Comment: Other questions on slow boot issues. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187117/slow-boot-boot-19-10-tried-almost-everything & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018576/what-does-networkmanager-wait-online-service-do & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/800479/ubuntu-16-04-slow-boot-apt-daily-service

Comment: @oldfred I tried all of the solution but nothing worked for me. The boot time is about 1 minute and 30s still.

Comment: Have you updated UEFI and if SSD the SSD firmware? Do you have a incorrect entry in fstab? Check UUIDs. Your systemd outputs look like the same issues as all the links posted.

Comment: @oldfred I've not updated my UEFI to the best of my knowledge. I am new to Linux platform I am afraid to answer about UUID entries in Fstab. But /dev/sda7 /dev/sda8 and /dev/sda9 are there in my machine. :(

Comment: Updating UEFI is not a Linux thing. Many systems still do not update UEFI from Linux. You either do it from Windows or directly within UEFI using instructions from the vendor of your system or motherboard. Do UUIDs of all partitions match UUIDs in fstab? `lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype,uuid,partuuid | egrep -v "^loop"`

Comment: @oldfred I matched UUID Of `sda1` `sda7`, `sda8`, `sda9` all of them matched exactly to each other.

Comment: @oldfred can it be a kernel problem I have 5.4 kernel running right now. I posted same question on Linux Mint forum, some expertise's were saying it may be due to WLAN configuration or Kernel problem also,

Comment: This mentions that you need a minimum of 5.4 for kernel. Which 20.04 has. https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=dell-xps7390-ubuntu1910&num=1

Comment: Get an SSD boot drive. My linux mint starts in seconds. The bios boot screen takes longer than the linux boot now.

Comment: You didn't provide a dmesg log. I had a similar problem [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366803/long-system-startup).

Comment: @BlueManCZ I added the dmesg log please have a look, I removed some enteries in the initial as the SO was allowing to cros 30000 limit.

Comment: @SurpriseDog Yea thinking of up gradation but right now trying to figuring out what is wrong with my boot up.

Comment: @oldfred I have also upgraded my Kernel to 5.8 but wasn't any helpful to me. :(

Answer (score 1):

*As a general answer, I'd say that, if you want to go quick to the root login... Irrespective of your hardware : Dont use systemd.
Using good old openrc, I reach the root login in less than 20s with my core 2. (4 Disks + 5 USB2 devices + 2 lans)* (*)

I don't know if your distro offers the choice of the init system but, if it does, do not hesitate.

More particularly, several operations your traces show take some amount of time irrespective of CPU power.
For example taken from your systemd-analyze critical-chain :

- **fsck** : (Filesystem check) Depending on the fsck options set, on the number of filesystems, their type, their make options, the fact that they are or not clean when booting... => check all these options. Whatever your cpu... these operations are time constrained.
- **timesyncd** : It seems your system is asking time from some time server. Depending on its availability, the time it will take to answer... Are your sure you need that to be achieved on every boot ? Are'nt you happy with the value saved at shutdown and the reliability of your battery backed internal clock ?
- **NetworkManager** : Being said that you don't need this for establishing ethernet lan links, I'll assume that you wan't to connect to some wifi.
  That just can take a huge time. Especially to wait for networkmanager to enumerate the available wifi networks. If you have convenient means to link to your internet router through some ethernet link. Do prefer!

Anyway, I acknowledge that networkmanager is convenient because its use does not require any particular knowledge from the user side. But, for basic security reasons, I would not be happy for that sort of service to start immediately at init time. I mean prior to having myself carried on a couple of sanity checks.

Etc...

<sup>(*) Italicized because it is my experience that I knew was shared in the early 2010s. *Krackout* gets a different one in his comment below.</sup>

Comment: Pentium M (2003) laptop with 768MB RAM, IDE disk, using systemd, Debian 10 32bit: Boots in 14sec. No DM, +3 sec for X.org+DWM. Systemd made every machine of mine boot faster; it's one of its pros, according to my experience. So if only boot time is considered, I do not think changing systemd is a wise choice. On a Core 2 like yours I had at the office, using Debian 8 Jessie (first Debian using systemd by default), HDD, booted in 10sec. Perhaps you should reconsider!

Comment: @Krackout : Fair enough. I modified my contribution. But I won't give LP a new chance. First because I'm getting too old and second because I know the reason for my abnormally high boot time. Because Intel did not provide any update for my core2 microcode... Spectre & misc other disgracefulities need mitigation, not to say about the necessary tricks to feed entropy in order to use blocking /dev/random... :-(